# Why am I getting a segmentation fault with the SQL Server ActiveRecord adapter?

Tags: sql-server, ruby, activerecord

isql runs just fine:

```
kobey:/etc# isql -v censored censored censored
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> select count(*) from Members;
+------------+
|            |
+------------+
| 1531       |
+------------+
SQLRowCount returns 1
1 rows fetched
SQL> quit
```

I have tested it with the Ruby ODBC driver:

```
irb(main):002:0> ODBC.connect('ANAME', 'censored', 'censored')
=> #<ODBC::Database:0x7fc95d428c80>
```

Here is my connection string for ActiveRecord:

```
Legacy::LegacyRecord.establish_connection({ :dsn => 'ANAME', :password => 'censored', :username => 'censored', :mode => 'odbc', :adapter => 'sqlserver', :encoding => 'utf8'})
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
>> Legacy::Member.first
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:970: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]

Aborted
```

Here are the versions of everything involved:

- Debian 5.0.4
- activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (2.3.8)
- freetds-common 0.82-4
- libct4 0.82-4
- libsybdb5 0.82-4
- freetds-dev 0.82-4
- libiodbc2 3.52.6-2
- libodbc-ruby1.8 0.9995-1
- libdbi-ruby1.8 0.2.2-1
- libdbd-odbc-ruby1.8 0.2.2-1
- libdbd-odbc-ruby 0.2.2-1
- odbcinst1debian1 2.2.11-16
- unixodbc 2.2.11-16
- libodbcinstq1c2 2.2.11-16
- tdsodbc 0.82-4
- unixodbc-dev 2.2.11-16

Configs:

odbcinst.ini:

```
[ODBC Drivers]
FreeTDS  = Installed

[FreeTDS]
Description     = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
Driver          = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsS.so
CPTimeout       =
CPReuse         =
FileUsage       = 1
```

odbc.ini:

```
[ODBC]
Trace = No

[ODBC Data Sources]
LATA = FreeTDS

[LATA]
Driver      = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Description = MS SQL Server connection to ANAME legacy database
ServerName  = ANAME
Database    = aname
```

freetds.conf:

```
[global]

[ANAME]
  host = 10.0.0.5
  tds version = 7.0
  client charset = UTF-8
  text size = 262144
  port = 1433
```

Does anybody have any idea what might cause this?

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same thing in ActiveRecord 3.0.6 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

After experiencing precisely the same problem, I've found a solution. Use the [TinyTDS](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds) library instead and avoid the crash in the ODBC library.

This reference on [using ActiveRecord with TinyTDS](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-TinyTds) explains more.

Answer (score 0):

First you no longer need dbd/dbi with the 2.3.8. Adapter.
Second:do you have a ntext or nvarchar(max) Field in your Table?

Comment: What problems does having ntext or nvarchar(max) field pose?